# Python to_csv the missing 0 in front of zipcode

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a data frame

USER =

```
   zipcode  userCount
0   00601   5
1   00602   23
2   00603   53
3   00604   2
4   00605   6
5   00606   10
6   00610   8
7   00612   33
8   00613   2
9   00614   2
10  00616   1
11  00617   9
12  00622   6
13  00623   28
14  00624   10
15  00627   8
16  00631   1
17  00637   13
18  00638   9
19  00641   12
20  00646   13
```

When I save it

```
USER.to_csv('Total_user.csv',index = False)
```

I got missing 0 in front of the zipcode. 00601 -> 601

```
zipcode userCount
601 5
602 23
603 53
604 2
605 6
606 10
610 8
612 33
613 2
614 2
616 1
617 9
622 6
623 28
624 10
627 8
631 1
637 13
638 9
641 12
646 13
```

Is that anything I missed in the to_csv line? I just want to save the 0 in front of the csv. Then when I read_csv(low_memory = False) Then the zipcode has the normal format.

Comment: how are you viewing the csv once you write it- excel?

Comment: You should store the column as a string before you save it to csv; this will keep anything funky like this from happening in saving.

Comment: @MattR has a good point. Excel might infer that the data are numeric and will chop off the leading zeros. Try viewing the CSV with a regular text editor, which will not alter your data.

Comment: right click , open as txt, you will see the lead 0 still there

Comment: This is a an excel display issue.

Comment: The issue is that the column should be treated as categorical rather than numerical either when reading / saving. Found a post online about this specific issue, hope it serves [http://data-tutorials.com/zip-codes-in-pandas.html](http://data-tutorials.com/zip-codes-in-pandas.html)

Comment: I agree with "This is a an excel display issue" cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ. The file will be normal if I open it with atom or notepad.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the column `df['zipcode']` of the first dataframe is already a column of strings, then save it this way:

```
>>> df.to_csv('zipcodes.csv',dtype={'zipcode':'str','userCount':int})
```

And then when reading, set all data types to be `str`, and then convert the ones that are not this way:

```
>>> pd.read_csv('zipcodes.csv',dtype='str',index_col=0)

   zipcode userCount
0    00601         5
1    00602        23
2    00603        53
3    00604         2
4    00605         6
5    00606        10
6    00610         8
7    00612        33
8    00613         2
9    00614         2
10   00616         1
11   00617         9
12   00622         6
13   00623        28
14   00624        10
15   00627         8
16   00631         1
17   00637        13
18   00638         9
19   00641        12
20   00646        13

>>> df['userCount'] = df['userCount'].astype(int)

>>> df.dtypes

zipcode      object
userCount     int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: This would be my solution

Comment: to_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'. This is the output for the code. Actually, I have no problem to read the csv. However, when save to csv, the 0 are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Your data probably being stored as an object type in the data frame. You can confirm this by typing:

```
df.dtypes
>>> zipCode      object
    userCount    object
    dtype: object
```

Python doesn't like 0 prefixed integers thus the object dtype. You'll need to quote your data when you save it. You can do this via the quoting parameter in read_csv()

```
import csv
df.to_csv('tmp.csv', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

If you don't quote your data pandas will convert it to an integer when you re-read it and strip the leading zeros.

Comment: when the OP reads in the dataframe again, he mentioned the leading zeros are still present.

Comment: This is the output of my dataframe '''zipcode      object
userCount     int64
dtype: object'''

Answer (score 0):

Please use `dtype=str` as a parameter to `read_csv(file,sep,dtype=str)` method.

That will fix the issue.